# spring boot 2 M5 oauth authentication issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Sprig boot 2 M5 and spring oauth 
I have this configuration for my oauth client app

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
        registration:
            my-client:
                client-id: blabla
                client-secret: asecret
                client-name: a name
                provider: my-provider
                scope: read
                redirect-uri: https://localhost:8780/dp
                authentication-method: basic
                authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
    provider:
        my-provider:
            authorization-uri: https://blabla/oauth-server/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://blaba/oauth-server/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: https://lmfr:8780/user
            user-name-attribute: username
```

I was expecting to be redirected to the login page of my Oauth provider but instead I get redirected to the default spring login page.

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `redirect-uri` then it should work

See also this [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11014)

Comment: actually I stopped working on this issue, it seems spring boot M5 is not ready to work with the latest spring oauth2